# Ruby/Cucumber - 'puts' causing trouble

Tags: ruby, macos, cucumber, appium

We have recently installed a copy of our framework on another machine, and for some reason we get an error when using 'puts' instead of 'Kernel.puts' (we use Ruby)

This isn't a huge issue, but we occasionally use 'puts' to write to the cucumber results file.

This onlyhappens on 1 machine, not the other. Both are mac minis, same specs.

Both machines have the same gemlist, the same version of Ruby etc (they were both installed almost simultaneously).

Anyone else seen this?

Log:

```
2015-06-30 14:44:59 +0100 OUT: Error: undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass 2015-06-30 14:44:59 +0100 OUT: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.rb:89:inwrite'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/formatter/gherkin_formatter_adapter.rb:166:in puts' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:181:inblock in send_to_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:insend_to_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:173:in broadcast' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:154:inputs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/user_interface.rb:14:in puts' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_world.rb:107:inputs'
/Users/jenkins/workspace/TEST-regression-test_trial_mini/automation/ios/features/support/hooks.rb:104:in block in <top (required)>' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:ininstance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in block in cucumber_instance_exec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:incucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in cucumber_instance_exec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_hook.rb:14:ininvoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:114:in invoke' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:102:inblock in execute_before'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:101:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:101:inexecute_before'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:15:in before' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:112:inblock in fire_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:111:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:111:infire_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:107:in before' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:98:inbefore_and_after'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:82:in block in with_hooks' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:incall'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in block (3 levels) in around' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:inblock in around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:in call' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:inexecute_around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in around' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:inblock (2 levels) in around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:in call' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:inaround'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:94:in around' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:81:inwith_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in execute' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:32:inblock in accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:79:in with_visitor' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:31:inaccept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:58:in block in visit_feature_element' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:inbroadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:57:in visit_feature_element' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:38:inblock in accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:inaccept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:27:in block in visit_feature' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:inbroadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:26:in visit_feature' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:inblock in accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:ineach'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:27:in accept' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:21:inblock in visit_features'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in broadcast' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:invisit_features'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:49:in run!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:inexecute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/bin/cucumber:13:in <top (required)>' /usr/bin/cucumber:23:inload'
/usr/bin/cucumber:23:in
```

Comment: Could you provide fragment of your code with `puts`?

Comment: Within the Cucumber step definitions, we have: puts "Generating Service Provider”. This is the method we are calling (in a separate class):             def puts( o )
  timenow = Time.now
  if o.is_a? Array
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o.to_s
  else
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o
  end
  super(msg.black)
end

Answer (score 0):

Something somewhere is overriding your `puts`. You'll just have to find it. As an alternative, use `warn`. From Avdi Grimm's *Exceptional Ruby*:

> puts leaves something to be desired as a failure reporting method, however. Because its output goes to $stdout, which is buffered by default, output may not be printed immediately, or it may come out in a surprising order
>
> warn is more succinct, while still using $stderr as its output stream. Note also that the output of warn can be temporarily silenced by passing the -W0 flag to Ruby.

Comment: Great - thanks very much! It's the first time I have ever seen a problem with puts, we'll implement your suggestion and see what happens.